# SQL Error: Tablespace does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running this script on sql oracle developer:-

```
DEFINE TABLESPACE1 = "&TABLESPACE1";
CREATE TABLE "DBUSER" 
(   
"USER_ID" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"USERNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"CREATED_DATE" DATE
) TABLESPACE "&TABLESPACE1" ;
```

I am getting this error:-

```
SQL Error: ORA-00959: tablespace '&TABLESPACE1' does not exist
00959. 00000 -  "tablespace '%s' does not exist"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE** Not all `SQL*Plus` commands are necessary to run in **SQL Developer**. Also, it depends on the SQL Developer version, the latest versions have a lot of SQL*Plus commands support.

I tested in **SQL Developer version 3.2.20.10**

`&` is used for **substitution variable** in `SQL*Plus` .

For example,

In `SQL*Plus`

```
SQL> DEFINE TABLESPACE1 = &TABLESPACE1
Enter value for tablespace1: new_tablespace
SQL> SELECT '&TABLESPACE1' from dual;
old   1: SELECT '&TABLESPACE1' from dual
new   1: SELECT 'new_tablespace' from dual

'NEW_TABLESPAC
--------------
new_tablespace

SQL>
```

In **SQL Developer**

```
DEFINE TABLESPACE1 = &TABLESPACE1

<Enter the value when prompted> -- I entered "t"

old:DEFINE TABLESPACE1 = &TABLESPACE1
new:DEFINE TABLESPACE1 = t
```

> SQL Error: ORA-00959: tablespace '&TABLESPACE1' does not exist
>
> 959. 00000 -  "tablespace '%s' does not exist"

Are you sure you are executing it as a **script** in **SQL Developer**. You could **press F5** to execute it as a script. Did you substitute the value for the variable?

For example,

```
SQL> DEFINE TABLESPACE1 = "&TABLESPACE1"
Enter value for tablespace1: new_tablespace
SQL> CREATE TABLE "DBUSER"
  2  (
  3  "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  4  "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  5  "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  6  "CREATED_DATE" DATE
  7  ) TABLESPACE "&TABLESPACE1" ;
old   7: ) TABLESPACE "&TABLESPACE1"
new   7: ) TABLESPACE "new_tablespace"
) TABLESPACE "new_tablespace"
             *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'new_tablespace' does not exist


SQL>
```

In your case, if the value is properly substituted, and if tablespace exists, you should be able to create the table.

Comment: But isn't it supposed to prompt me to enter tablespace name when I run the script?

Comment: Not all `SQL*Plus` commands are necessary to run in SQL Developer. Also, it depends from version to version, the latest versions have a lot of `SQL*Plus` commands support. Your version might not be supporting it.

Comment: There may be some bug in the version I'm using. I reconnected the connection and ran the script, it prompted me to enter tablespace and the ddl worked fine. Thanks for you sharing, though

Comment: That's nice. Please mark it as answered, would help others.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you entered a value '&TABLESPACE1' into TABLESPACE1 substitution variable. Maybe you have substitution scanning off. Try

```
SET SCAN ON
```

before your statement

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
DROP TABLE "DBUSER";
UNDEFINE TABLESPACE1
DEFINE TABLESPACE1 = 'USERS'
CREATE TABLE "DBUSER" 
(   
"USER_ID" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"USERNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"CREATED_DATE" DATE
) TABLESPACE "&TABLESPACE1." ;
/

SQL> DROP TABLE "DBUSER";
UNDEFINE TABLESPACE1
DEFINE TABLESPACE1 = 'USERS'
CREATE TABLE "DBUSER"
(
"USER_ID" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
"USERNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
"CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
"CREATED_DATE" DATE
) TABLESPACE "&TABLESPACE1." ;
/
Table dropped.

SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7  alt   7: ) TABLESPACE "&TABLESPACE1."
neu   7: ) TABLESPACE "USERS"

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your table space name is :"&TABLESPACE1"?

Try to test **if your table space exist** with :

```
select Tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces 
where Tablespace_name = 'yourtablespacename';
```

Comment: There is define statement for substitution variable. When the script is executed in SQL Plus, user is prompted for  value of the variable. Sorry for downvoting, but this is not an answer.